# temp tables in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, temp-tables

I'm coming from a background in SQL Server where I would create temp tables using the:

```
    select id
    into #test
    from table A
```

I've just moved into a PostGresql environment and I was hoping I could do the same, but I'm getting a syntax error.  I did a search and it seems like you have to do a Create Table statement.

Is it not possible to easily create temp tables in Postgres?

Comment: A temp table can be created like so: `CREATE TEMP TABLE my_table AS SELECT id FROM a`. However generally things can be solved without using temp tables.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres supports [`SELECT INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html), so this should work fine:

```
SELECT id
INTO TEMP TABLE test
FROM a
```

You can also use [`CREATE TABLE AS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE test AS
  SELECT id FROM a
```

This version is generally preferred, as the `CREATE` statement provides additional options, and can also be used in PL/pgSQL functions (where the `SELECT INTO` syntax has been hijacked for variable assignment).

Comment: If I try the Create TEMP Table option I get a "read only" permissions error.  That's why I liked the SQL Server INTO # TABLE method.

Comment: @jackstraw22: Works fine for me, if it doesn't work for you then you'll need to give us a little more context